# Preserve environment variables using systemd?

Tags: environment-variables, systemd

Do `systemd` unit files support preserving existing environment variables?

(Something similar to `sudo -E`?)

*Not* referring to `Environment=` or `EnvironmentFile=` here.

It would be be useful if `systemd` could for example leave the `DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE` environment variable intact. Then the service had a chance to determine wheter it was restarted as part of a an upgrade (`apt-get` / `dpkg` set the `DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE`environment variable.) vs manually/at boot.

Answer (score 6):

That would not make sense because the started service is not a child of the process which caused the start. `systemctl` connects to the running `systemd` and makes it start the processes. So even if the environment was preserved (maybe it even is...) then it would be `systemd`'s environment that gets inherited. And that does not contain the entries you want.